# Android Gingerbread buffering with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, streaming, android-mediaplayer, android-version

I try to implement a simple media player to play an audio stream from an external URL. Pretty simple I guess. Tried to implement this sample from Androïd dev site http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.html

It works just fine with 2.1. 
Then, with 2.2 it gets weird. Starts just well, but takes almost 10 seconds to stop.
With 2.3, it's not better. This time might take up to a minute to start playing, but stops OK.

Does anyone have a clue why ? I also did try the prepareAsync way with the listner, but it never get called. Any help would be appreciated at this point. Thanks !

Comment: I just took a test with GSM connection under 2.3. It takes 2:43 minutes and hangs after a few minutes... Not good at all.

Answer (score 0):

Register setOnInfoListener() and control start buffering, end buffering and so on.
Look at the android documentation [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnInfoListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener%29)